# Setting up RTMP for streaming (Console)

Tags: networking, ssh, iptables, dd-wrt, video-streaming

So I have been trying to set this up for the past few days and I am having so much trouble actually getting this to work.

I have installed Nginx with the optional RTMP module onto my Mac and I also have my Router (WNDR4000) flashed with DD-WRT. I have done everything that every step by step guide has told me to do inside nginx but I get the same error after I try to modify the config file to use the RTMP signal. Every time I add the RTMP to the buttom of the config, I end up getting a unknown directive "rtmp" and nothing will work. I need this up to make sure that even the IPtables that I have tried to put into the router are working. I have been working on this for the past few days with very little success and want to actually get this working as this is not only a private venture but something I am trying to work on for other people.

Please if anyone knows what is going on any help would be appreciated. I will warn you though that my coding skills are not up to par so I would appreciate a bit more laymen's terms if possible. I don understand some of it, but the actual part of doing it just doesn't sit with me well and I am just not sure why.

I would be very greatful for any help as hours of scouring the internet has brought me nothing but more questions and issues.

EDIT: Here is the Config file:

```
user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

    }

    include servers/*;
}
```

Here is the RTMP Section:

```
rtmp {  
server {
    listen 1935;
    application app {
        live on;
        recorder storage {
            record all;
            record_path /user/austingoss/desktop
            record_unique on;
            exec_record_done /user/austingoss/desktop/.encode.sh $path $basename;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you,

AG

Comment: Can you edit your question with the output of `nginx -V` and the relevant portions of your config file?

Comment: There you go, I just put the entire config there

Comment: And the output of `nginx -V`??

Comment: Not to be that guy, but say what? My terminology is quite lacking because as I said I just pretty much did what other posts on other sites told to me to do to get it working, and it is not. So I figured I would come here to hopefully get some help in possibly plain english

Comment: Open the Terminal app and type `nginx -V`.  This will tell us information about your nginx installation.

Comment: it is saying 1.8.0